# Python doesn't find standard default path for SSL keys on Windows

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping, mechanize

to tell you the truth, I don't have much idea why this error is occurring, I've been using the same development environment for about 3 months, for study, today when I sat down to study I came across the following problem. My application uses flask as a backend for a website and Beuatifull Soup and mechanize to collect information, through scraping.

[Here is the problem log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZmVk.png)

Note: I didn't put even a snippet of code from the project, because the error came up without me changing anything and the path 'C:\User\gabri\SSLKeys\sslkeylog.log' exists.

Check the file path and try to add a new path but the error remains

Answer (score 0):

the path is `C:\Users\gabi...`, not `C:\User\gabi...` (User vs Users)...clearly someone changed something with this code from when it was working
[image]